# Server Rendered Vue Nuxt

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, express, nuxt.js

Мне нужны советы. Хочу на сервере выполнить функцию с помощью `nuxt.js`. Не совсем понимаю как это реализовать. Информции не много (гугл страниц много пролистал). Создал проект `nuxt`, нашел точку входа (ниже), но как понять что функция именно на сервере отработала, как ее запустить на сервере, что смотреть, где искать. Нужна любая информация по этой теме, не стесняйтесь, пишите ;)

```
<template>
  <nuxt/>
</template>
```